# After removing lines in my jQuery dialog a scrollbar is displayed only with IE

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery dialog where I add/remove lines on it.

[image]

When I remove lines (using the trash button) I see a scroll bar with Internet Explorer 9.

No problem with Chrome.

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this css to the correct div:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Its probably the outer most one `.ui-dialog` or the content div `.ui-dialog-content`.